# Magento 2.4.3 p2 Special price date expire on default store timezone

Tags: magento2

I have multiple websites on magento 2.4.3-p2 and we run campaigns with schedule special price. but special price expire before schedule time it does not work on specific store timezone For example I have two website NZ and AU and schedule special price on specific store on 20-dec-2022 both campaign are expiring by default timezone which is nz i want to expire AU campaign on AU timezone

Comment: did you configured time zone setting website-store wise?

Comment: Yes it is configured on store level but it is not working